# Добавить сортировку в sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Привет всем!
Питаюсь добавить тут сортировка по рандомно но почему то выдает ошибка помогите если не сложно.

```
if ($query->num_rows == 0) {
    $sql = "
        SELECT *, p.product_id as related_id 
        FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p 
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s 
            ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
        WHERE p.product_id IN (
            SELECT product_id 
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category  where category_id IN (
                SELECT category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category 
                WHERE product_id=".(int)$product_id."
            )
        ) 
        AND p.status = '1'
        AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
        AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'
        LIMIT 8
    ";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: собственно, а где тут сама сортировка у вас?

Comment: что-то запутались вы по моему не в сортировке а подзапросах

Comment: После LIMIT 8 добавляю ORDER random но ошибка выдает

Answer (score 1):

Решение

```
if($query->num_rows==0)
    {
        $sql="  select *,p.product_id as related_id  from " . DB_PREFIX . "product p  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) where p.product_id in   (select product_id from " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category  where category_id in  (SELECT category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category where product_id=".(int)$product_id."))  AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'ORDER BY RAND() limit 8";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    }
```